# how to Manipulate duplicated records using access

Tags: ms-access, duplication, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

Using Microsoft Access, I have a number of records that have duplicated field-1. I need to form a query such that the duplicate records get unique ; BUT the next filed-2 data must be seen in columns next to each other the same no. of times. For example, now I have a table like this:

```
field-1  | field-2
1        | date1 
2        | date1 
1        | date2
3        | date1
3        | date2
1        | date3
```

And query output needed:

```
field-1  | (1st-duplicate) | (2nd-duplicate) | (3rd-duplicate) | .... (nth-duplicate)
1        | date1           | date2           | date3
2        | date1 
3        | date1           | date2
```

How I can do that ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access: Making a Pivot Table with Multiple, Same Values as Columns](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/227664/access-making-a-pivot-table-with-multiple-same-values-as-columns)

Comment: Could you please put the code for this query.